# Android Refreshing Custom ListView using DataSetObserver

Tags: java, android, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

I'm using a custom adapter for listview, and created a class for custom data.

Currently I'm implementing ListAdapter in CustomAdapter class.

By using ListAdapter implementation, I'm not getting notifyDataSetChanged to call when a new data added. I extended the BaseAdapter and tried using the notifyDataSetChanged, It's working, but only when I click on another control in activity the data is getting loaded.

```java
        date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);


                if(isFrom){
                    from=sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
                    fY.setText(from);
                }else{
                    to=sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
                    tY.setText(to);
                }
                getTransactions();
            }

        };
```

getTransactions(); will be called when the date selected in **from** field.
But, only when I click the to field, the data is appearing in ListView.

```java
    private void getTransactions() {
        Cursor c=billnDB.getBill();
        billData.clear();
        TransactionBillData data=new TransactionBillData();
        data.setBill_number("ID");
        data.setBill_number("Bill Number");
        data.setDate("Date");
        data.setTotal("Total");
        billData.add(data);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            Log.v("Products Moved to First", "True");
            do{
                Log.v("Bill Number",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")));

                data=new TransactionBillData();
                data.setBill_number(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")));
                data.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
                data.setTotal(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("total")));
                billData.add(data);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                addLayout(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("total")));
            }while (c.moveToNext());

        }
    }
```

This is my Adapter

```java
public class TransactionsBillAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
...
}
```

I need another option instead this notifyDataSetChanged();